# How to remove "Invisible space" from HTML

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

I have a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RhvjF/) of my html code. Here is the code here:

```
<span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span>
<span style="display: none;"></span>
<span style="display: inline">rld</span>​
```

The problem I'm having is that an extra space is being inserted between the 'o' and the 'r' in Hello World!. The `display` style is set to none, so can someone please tell me how I can get the `Hello World!` phrase without the space?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The linebreaks are causing it - http://jsfiddle.net/RhvjF/1/

Can't find the particular post, but smart people suggested 3 ways of fixing it:

1. Put everything in one line (remove all line breaks)
2. Comment out the line breaks, like

   ```
   <span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span><!--
   --><span style="display: none;"></span><!--
   --><span style="display: inline">rld</span>
   ```
3. Set the container `font-size` to `0` and re-set it for `span`-s

**UPDATE**

There are at least 2 more ways:

1. Break the tags, like

   ```
   <span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span
   ><span style="display: none;"></span
   ><span style="display: inline">rld</span>
   ```
2. Float the elements, i.e. `span { float: left }`

Comment: The fact that the line breaks are causing the issue seems like such an obvious answer, but I didn't see it. Thank you for the help

Comment: you are welcome :) most people have this issue with `<li>`-s though

Comment: For completeness, the other way is to break the lines inside the tags, as per the second example on this page from the HTML5 spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-section-element.html#the-section-element

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of solutions #2 or #(4). It makes the markup less readable.

Comment: @Shmiddty they are verbose indeed, but they exist and someone might find them useful, so it wouldn't be fair to exclude solutions based on personal preferences :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth But, think of the children! Someone else will be handling this code at some point, surely.

Comment: @Shmiddty Children should read the comments too and there they'll find your warning

Answer (score 8):

This is caused by line breaks. You have two choices:

1. Remove the line breaks
2. Float your content.

**Option 1**

```
<span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span><span style="display: none;"></span><span style="display:inline">rld</span>​
```

**Option 2**

```
<style>
    #spanContainer > span { float:left; }​
</style>

<div id="spanContainer">
    <span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span>
    <span style="display: none;"></span>
    <span style="display: inline">rld</span>​
</div>
```

Comment: There's (at least) a third choice, see my answer

Comment: @Oriol, See Tyler's point on your answer

Comment: It is easier for me to put the tags on one line rather then mess with the CSS styling. I am actually using absolute font sizes, so as Tyler pointed out, Oriol's solution probably wouldn't be the best solution for me. For me, deleting the line breaks and putting it one line is the best option.

Answer (score 5):

See http://jsfiddle.net/RhvjF/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span style="display: inline">Hello Wo</span>
    <span style="display: none;"></span>
    <span style="display: inline">rld</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    font-size:0;
}
#wrapper>*{
    font-size:16px; /* Or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: One can't use relative font sizes when using the strategy, though.