# CSS based table layout: inconsistent behavior of inline-block placement

Tags: css

I am trying to recreate a table element using inline blocks of fixed width, and I am suffering an apparently inconsistent behavior from the browsers (Chrome and IE) in spacing elements.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

the problem is that the first in the top two rows (which should act as headers and are part of the static HTML of the page) the `span` get a strange spacing on the right - as you can read below from the CSS there is a margin of 0 declared (this is obviously a WIP, some `span` should just be replaced by `div`s etc. so pls bear with me.).

If I instead add dynamically the rows at run time through Javascript, I get the two rows below - which is the expected behavior. In blue you can find the container of these rows - 100% of the `div` element including all of this. 
Ther reason I am using this approach instead of a normal table is that I want to have the dynamic data rows scrollable, which is not achieveable in a neat way with a `table`.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <span class="cssTRC">
            <span>
                <span>Day</span>
                <span>Loc</span>
                <span>Nagare</span>
                <span>Pcs</span>
                <span>Packs</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <span>Thu 30 Aug</span>
                <span>E5-1</span>
                <span>{only DI}</span>
                <span>480</span>
                <span>1</span>
            </span>
    </span>
   <span id="ctblrcOrdHist" class="cssTRC">
         <span>
              <span>Thu 30 Aug</span>
              <span>E5-1</span>
              <span>DI</span>
              <span>480</span>
              <span>1</span>
         </span> 
         <span>
            <span>Thu 30 Aug</span>
            <span>KE-1</span>
            <span>DI</span>
            <span>500</span> 
            <span>1</span>
         </span>
      </span>
```

and the CSS, defined as follows:

```
.cssTH>span>span,.cssTRC>span>span
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:5em;
    padding:0.2em;
    margin:0;
    border:0 solid red/*#E8EEF4;*/;
    border-width:0 0 1px 1px;
}
.cssTH>span, .cssTRC>span
{
    display:block;
}
.cssTRC
{
    border:0 solid #E8EEF4;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0 ;
    display:block;
    /*max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;*/
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

The question is obviously how I can get the expected behavior for the first two rows without adding the pseudo-header at run time (which sounds horrible).

**EDIT**

I write down the solution I consider more handy so that this can work also as a small example of basic CSS table layout, in case someone might need it:

```
            <div>
                 <span>Day</span
                ><span>Loc</span
                ><span>Nagare</span
                ><span>Pcs</span
                ><span>Packs</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem cause by whitespace between your spans - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrsUk/)

I've used the `float` fix in this example. For more ways of fixing this issue you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183374/1499781)

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, my bad, it is not the first time I fall in this trap, still did not manage to hammer in my head. Still cannot understand the reason of this, but yep, that's the issue.

Comment: you are welcome :) I know that most of these cases occurs with `<li>`-s, so when it happens with other elements (which usually behave "correctly") it's not the first thing you think about

Answer (score 2):

Leave no space between `</span>` and `<span>` when using `inline-block` (any kind of whitespace you might have between two elements matters when you're using `display: inline-block` on them).

Like this:

```
<span>Day</span><span>Loc</span>
```

When you add them via JavaScript, no whitespace is inserted between the closing tag and the next opening tag, that's why it looks fine in that case.