# Why is it not working as intended in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

[image: Intended Behavior of The Navigation]

[image: IE7 Behavior of the Navigation]

Due to Intellectual Property issues with the client I just can't discuss any code.

There is a line or space between two `LI` tags in IE7 which are not present in Firefox or Chrome.

I tried very hard to detect where is the problem. I think after 6 hourse of try. So any fresh ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Can't you distil the problem into a subset and show us that?

Comment: yes that is correct. I will try and edit the question as much as possible.

Comment: You know HTML & CSS are going to be public anyway once the site is deployed, it's the nature of the web...

Comment: I'll think this is a IE6/7 specific Bug called whitespace Bug

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12183374/1499781

Comment: Yes whitespace is normalized but significant in XML and therefore many browsers

Comment: As I rembember this can be fixed by margin:0, padding:0 and overflow:hidden you force all LI tag to be touched

Comment: this is tagged `css3`, but IE7 doesn't support any CSS3 features.

Comment: @Spudley I am so sorry. I will remove the tag. 

#ALL Thanks for your help. SO Rocks.

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah Look into a lightweight CSS reset to set some the defaults a lot of browsers tend to vary on. Yahoo YUI 2's, I think was a decent one.

Comment: Are your LI elements floating?

Comment: i found the problem! it's IE!!!

Comment: @BillyMoat Yes I am using floats. but not for the elements which are coming in dropdown. they are the top level elements. 

THIS BEHAVIOR is also just when I hover over my mouse not otherwise. It is working fine otherwise.

Comment: I suspect IE might be having problems with CSS the `line-height`, `margin` or `padding` properties. However, without the actual code it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to integrate a good CSS Reset (good one you can found on www.html5boilerplate.com ).

Second, I can only suppose menu CSS/HTML code (why you don't publish here the code? When is online, EVERY person can read your css/js/html code!):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
     <li>menu item</li>
     <li>menu with subitem
         <ul>
            <li>sub menu item</li>
            ...
         </ul>
     </li>
     ...
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul {
   ...
```

}

I can suggest this kind of reset:

```
.menu ul, .menu li {
   margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   display: block;
   list-style: none;
}
```

and try to obtain other padding/spacing with sub elements (`span`, `a`, ecc.).

Comment: I think the problem got solved it had some client side css missing so after including those, it did solve the problem. THANKS A LOT.