# Line break displayed in ul li

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969082/unwanted-margin-in-inline-block-list-items)
>   [How to remove “Invisible space” from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183341/how-to-remove-invisible-space-from-html)

I have an `<ul>` with multiple `<li>` children.

The `li`'s just contain an image, and I removed all the margin from them.
I also called `display:inline-block;` on them, so they are now displayed in one line.

However, there is still a small margin on the right side of the `li`s.
I found out that it's the line break, and that, if I remove it the margin disappear.
However, it's very unreadable if I have to remove all the line breaks.

Can you give me a solution for this one?

---

### HTML

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="#"><img src="image1.png" alt="post_heart" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image2.png" alt="post_repeat" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image3.png" alt="post_tag" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image4.png" alt="post_share" /></a></li>

</ul>
```

---

### LESS

```
ul {
    display:inline;
    padding:none;
    margin:none;

    li {
        display:inline-block;

        padding:none;
        margin:none;

        a {
            display:block;  
            margin:none;
            border-right: 1px solid #e0e1e2;

            &:hover {
                .linearGradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.05));
            }
        }

        &:last-child {
            a {
                border:none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you create a JSFiddle for this.

Comment: here are your choices - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12183374/1499781

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted the question, I've ran into this issue before.

Comment: I feel like I answer this question every other day.

Comment: @cimmanon Sorry I wasn't aware that it's because of the `inline-block`, therefore I didn't find the right solution via search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "margin" is actually whitespace (some combination of tabs, spaces, or newlines).  You can keep your formatting by commenting it out.

```
<ul><!--
    --><li><img /></li><!--
    --><li><img /></li><!--
    --><li><img /></li><!--
    --><li><img /></li><!--
    --><li><img /></li><!--
--></ul>
```

See also:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Seems odd, I have never seen this. Is there no other way to prevent this?

Comment: You can float the elements instead of displaying inline-block.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall yes, you can use floats to get roughly the same effect.  However, if you're interested in centering the list instead of having it appear to either the right or left of the page, floats make it tougher to do so.

Comment: @cimmanon It's ok, the list should be aligned left anyway

Comment: @cimmanon Floating the LI's, not the list itself. But I agree it does add other things to consider using floats.

Comment: sorry, yes, that's what I meant. The list is aligned left, so it won't cause any troubles if the li's are left aligned too.

Comment: convenient alternative: using `<?php ... ?>` as a gap filler

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have no margin on the li's.

I've also ran into the this issue using inline-block, that in your markup, you can't have any white space between li elements or it will render it. Looks ugly, but worked.

E.g **This**

```
<ul>
<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</u>
```

instead of this

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's essential the same answer as cimmanon?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wrote in the question that I'd like to avoid this. cimmanon's answer helped me.

Comment: Ahh, np. Glad you have it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Just make them `float:left`. When they are `display:inline` there is always a space about 3px I think.

Comment: This would be the best alternative.

Comment: I have tried everything to remove the space on display:inline elements but only this seems to be a solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesn't seem to be the problem.