# How do I achieve horizontal spacing inside <p class="..."> in html?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu bar and just want to horizontal spacing between a text and hyperlink.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="rectangle">
<p class="x">Home Page
 <a href="hello">Home</a> <a href="user">user</a></p>
</div>
```

In the style field, I have

```
p.x {
        color: white;
        font:25px arial,sans-serif;
        position:relative;
        left:20px;
    }

#rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 20;
    }
```

I want to have space betwwen "Home Page" and "Home"/"user".

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Its spaces in your html file. You can read about it here[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183341/how-to-remove-invisible-space-from-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `<a>` some horizontal margin. So you can simply do:

```
.x a:first-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

However, you probably want to check out how to properly make navigation buttons if that's what you want. Using [`<nav>`](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/) you can achieve this in html5.

Comment: This kind of works, but I don't need spaces between two hyperlinks. How do I acheive that?

Comment: I didn't get that clear from the OP. Updated, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. .x a:first-child would select the first <a> of class "x", correct?

Comment: Exactly. An alternative would be to set a class specifically which would also make it more compatible to very old versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to that.

Try the CSS "margin" or "padding" property.

1. [Margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)
2. [Padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)