# Where is this space coming from between two elements?

Tags: html, css

between these two p elements.

I checked the box model and there is no margin set.

Here it the fiddle and code -

https://jsfiddle.net/f3m2apgy/

```
<body>

<style>
#container{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
#si_but{
  cursor:  pointer;
  padding:  14px 14px;  
  font-size: 14px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#su_but{
  cursor:  pointer;
  padding:  14px 14px;  
  font-size: 14px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;

}
#hold_button{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
</style>


<div id="container">
  <divi id="hold_button">
    <p id='si_but' class='blue_but   radius_left  medium_white'>SignIn</p>
    <p id='su_but' class='orange_but radius_right medium_white'>SignUp</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Read: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/. Use `float: left` on `p`. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f3m2apgy/4/)

Comment: Here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12183341/1499781

Comment: @Tushar - thanks that is like 8 answers in 1 comment

Comment: No need to use floats here.

Comment: Also note that it is recommended to omit the unit for `0` lengths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `newline` after the first `</p>` and indenting `spaces` before the second `<p>`.

If you put `<p>` elements in a line, the space will disappear.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="hold_button">
        <p id='si_but' class='blue_but radius_left medium_white'>SignIn</p><p id='su_but' class='orange_but radius_right medium_white'>SignUp</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, `<divi>` should be typo of `<div>`.

Comment: answer is in the comments

Answer (score 1):

It's because all inline-block elements have a space to the left if seperated by spaces in the HTML code. To fix it, you should change them to `<ul>` or `<div>` elements, or add a negative margin to one of them.
Adding `margin-left: -5px;` to `#su_but` would also fix this, although it is a little hacky.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `<p>` elements on a single line in your code, the gap is eliminated.

```
<p id='si_but' class='blue_but   radius_left  medium_white'>SignIn</p><p id='su_but' class='orange_but radius_right medium_white'>SignUp</p>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/f3m2apgy/6/

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to fix the whitespace problems coming up with `display: inline-block;` is to set the parent element's font-size to zero. Of course the consequence is that you will have to re-set the necessary font-size on the child elements - which you already do in your example, so

```
#hold_button { font-size: 0; }
```

fixes your problem already.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3m2apgy/7/