# Vertically align children inside parent with dynamic height, using inline-block and vertical-align: middle and top?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a list view control shuttle with add/remove buttons

Something like a control similar to this VB (gross) image example I found:

[image: basic visual example]

but with only the add `>` and remove `<` buttons vertically aligned in the middle.

First I tried floating to accomplish the side by side `ul`s and buttons, but I couldn't take care of vertically positioning the buttons in the center of the container.

I looked into a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430929/css-vertically-align-floating-divs/9431102#9431102) using `inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle`, which works if I applied it to all containers. However, I want the `ul`s aligned to the top.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inblock vert-top">
    <ul>
      <li>item list view</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="inblock vert-middle">
    <div>
      <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>&lt;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inblock vert-top">
    <ul>
      <li>item list view</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inblock {
  display: inline-block;  
  /* IE 7 hack */
  *zoom:1;
  *display: inline;
}

.inblock.vert-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.inblock.vert-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/2ZCAe (similar to jsFiddle)

Using `.inblock.vert-middle` does not work for the second `ul`, when it is applied, it sends the button container to the top. However, using `.inblock.vert-middle` for the second `ul` displays how I want it, but it doesn't make sense.

How do I fix the CSS so it makes sense for the second `ul`, or how do I vertically align these buttons correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but a table would do the job. `vertical-align: middle` applied to `display: table-cell` elements will cause the content to center vertically.

Comment: Works like a charm. Knew I should have tried `table-cell` I saw it a few times as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: **Note:** `display:table-cell` isn't supported by IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a `DOCTYPE` in the HTML to support it. If either of those are an issue, use an HTML `table` tag, if editing the HTML is an option.