# Vertically aligning images in floated elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertical align some images to the **bottom** in floated elements, and I can't seem to get it to cooperate.

Here is a JSFiddle with an example. You can see they are aligning to the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/decr9gfj/1/

Some Code:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x150"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x100"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x75"></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#eee;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

li {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 5px;
}

a {
    display:block;
}

img {
    display:block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css vertically align floating divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430929/css-vertically-align-floating-divs)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float on the list items and add display:inline-block.

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 5px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/decr9gfj/3/)

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#eee;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 5px;
}
a {
    display:block;
}
img {
    display:block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
 * html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x150"></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x100"></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/100x75"></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need it to happen in floated elements as the title states, I'm aware of the inline-block method.

Comment: Floated elements don't obey vertical-align. At least not without some hacky workarounds.

Comment: How hacky are these workarounds? I'm currently fiddling with trying to absolutely position the images within the div to the bottom.