# How to vertically align a div within another div when using bootstrap row and columns?

Tags: html, css

how to vertically middle the left and right divs below when using bootstrap and it should also be responsive?

```
<div class="test row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left col-md-3">
            <label> Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-md-9">
            <input type="text" value="input" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    .test {
        border: solid 1px;

        .wrapper {
            border: solid 1px brown;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;

            .left {
                border: solid 1px blue;
            }

            .right {
                border: solid 1px red;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've seen this but it doesn't work with bootstrap row and columns: [css vertically align floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430929/css-vertically-align-floating-divs)

Comment: This is not `css`, might be `less` or `sass`, but not `css`

Comment: ^ That's probably why it doesn't work

Comment: it's sass yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

```
.test {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: flex is not compatible with IE 9.https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: @Dynamic The browsers and versions you want answers to target should be in your question.

Comment: Nobody cares about IE9